# How to wrap JSON to a javascript function call

Tags: python, django-views

I need to be able to return a JSON file from a view via the django server using python. If however the url HTTP request contains a parameter named callback I have to wrap it in a javascript function call which is named after the 'callback' parameter. I have been able to create the JSON-file and send it to the server and I know how to retrieve the possible callback parameter. However I am confused about the way I have to wrap the JSON-file to the Javascript function call. Can anybody tell me the correct way?

```
def function_json(request, param):
    function_call = request.GET.get('callback', "")
    json_stuff = Object.objects.all().filter(param=parameter)
    if len(json_stuff) == 0:
        return HttpResponse("page was not found",status=404)
    data = {}
    for x in range(0, len(countries)):
        data[json_stuff[x].code] = json_stuff[x].name
    my_json_data = json.dumps(data)
    my_json_data_wrapped_in_a_function_call = ???
    return HttpResponse(my_json_data_wrapped_in_a_function_call, content_type="application/json")
```

and the data should show in server as

```
Function_call({json_stuff})
```

Comment: This is too vague. Please show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming  `callback` is the string `"Function_call"` and the expected result is the string `"Function_call({xxx:yyy});", then it's just a matter of string formatting:

```
my_json_data_wrapped_in_a_function_call = "{callback}(json);".format(
    callback=callback, 
    json=json_stuff
    )
```

Note that this is javascript code, not json, so the response's content type should not be "application/json" anymore.

Unrelated, but this:

```
json_stuff = Object.objects.all().filter(param=parameter)
data = {}
for x in range(0, len(json_stuff)):
    data[json_stuff[x].code] = json_stuff[x].name
```

could be seriously improved. First, python's `for` loop are really 'foreach' loops - you are iterating over a sequence, with the iteration variable (the 'x' in `for x in ...`) set to the current item from the sequence, so your above `for` loop should be:

```
data = {}
for item in json_stuff:
    data[item.code] = item.name
```

which can be simplified further using a dict expression:

```
data = {item.code: item.name for item in json_stuff}
```

or if your python version is too old using a generator expression and the `dict` constructor:

```
data = dict((item.code, item.name) for item in json_stuff)
```

but actually since you're using the Django orm, you don't need any of this, you can get it already backed, sliced and packed:

```
data = Object.objects.filter(param=parameter).values("code", "name")
```

NB: `Model.objects.all().filter()` or the more common `Model.objects.filter().all()` variant are redundant. You only need `.all()` if you have no other `filter()`, `exclude()`, `values()` or whatever queryset method call to invoke.